# Is it possible to query the result of the action server?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'd like to use polling instead of callbacks.
Is it possible to query the result of the action server as it was the case in ROS1 with `action_client->get_state()` ?
I can't find an equivalent in ROS2 Humble.

Clement

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413678/is-it-possible-to-query-the-result-of-the-action-server?/) by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2023-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS 2 Humble, when you send out a goal with "async_send_goal", assign the returned future goal handle to a variable. When you need to query for the result, you can just call "[async_get_result](https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp_action/classrclcpp__action_1_1Client.html#a0213daa95ba7b1229d1371fad47b23b5)" or "[async_result](https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp_action/classrclcpp__action_1_1ClientGoalHandle.html)" (deprecated). For example:

```
auto future_goal_handle = client_ptr_->async_send_goal(goal_msg, send_goal_options);
rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete(node, future_goal_handle);
auto result = client_ptr_-> async_get_result(future_goal_handle.get());
if (result.get().code == rclcpp_action::ResultCode::SUCCEEDED)
{
    return true;
}
```

Note that the "result" you get is a [WrappedResult](https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp_action/structrclcpp__action_1_1ClientGoalHandle_1_1WrappedResult.html), so if you want the result message, you need to do something like:

```
result.get().result
```

You can also query for goal status through the client goal handle with "[get_status](https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp_action/classrclcpp__action_1_1ClientGoalHandle.html#a154456949c16b697741c28705d7fdfeb)" if you are comparing with `action_client->get_state()` instead.

---

Originally posted by [GuimingChen](https://answers.ros.org/users/52726/guimingchen/) with karma: 56 on 2023-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on 2023-03-23**:
Thank you @GuimingChen!

**Comment by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on 2023-03-23**:
@GuimingChen The execution get stucked at `auto result = client_ptr_-> async_get_result(future_goal_handle.get());` :(
The action is well executed though

**Comment by [GuimingChen](https://answers.ros.org/users/52726/guimingchen/) on 2023-03-23**:
hmm... interesting, I thought this should return immediately since it is a std::shared_future.
Did it give you any error message?
Can you print something in the server side to check [which status](https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp_action/classrclcpp__action_1_1ServerGoalHandleBase.html) the goal is currently in when it got stucked? You can try access the goal status in handle accepted callback.

**Comment by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on 2023-03-23**:
No, there is no error, it just block at the async_get_result() call.
On the server side, the _execute() callback is correctly executed, I can see the message "Goal succeeded" in the terminal.

```
void SpacecraftController::change_si_state_execute(const std::shared_ptr<GoalHandleChangeSIState> goal_handle)
{
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Executing goal");
    const auto goal = goal_handle->get_goal();

    auto result = std::make_shared<ChangeSIState::Result>();
    if (emitSiCmd(*goal))
    {
        result->nb_si_handled = goal->si_list.size();
        goal_handle->succeed(result);
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Goal succeeded");
    }
}
```

**Comment by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on 2023-03-23**:
The goal status in the `_accepted()` callback is `is_active=1`, `is_executing=1` and `is_canceling=0`

**Comment by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on 2023-03-23**:
The goal status at the end of the `_execute()` callback is `is_active=0`, `is_executing=0` and `is_cancelling=0`

**Comment by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on 2023-03-23**:
Actually there is an error if I kill the blocking node with CTRL+C:

```
    [ERROR] [1679587180.654655117] [rclcpp]: caught std::exception exception when uninstalling signal handlers in rclcpp::~SignalHandler: Invalid argument
cannot publish data, at ./src/rmw_publish.cpp:62 during '__function__'
    [ERROR] [1679587180.656454559] [sequencer.rclcpp]: Error in destruction of rcl subscription handle: Failed to delete datareader, at ./src/subscription.cpp:52, at ./src/rcl/subscription.c:183
cannot publish data, at ./src/rmw_publish.cpp:62 during '__function__'
    Fail in delete datareader, at ./src/rmw_service.cpp:104 during '__function__'
    [ros2run]: Segmentation fault
```

**Comment by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on 2023-03-23**:
I tried

```
auto future_goal_handle = action_client->async_send_goal(goal_msg, send_goal_options);
RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Goal handle valid =%d", future_goal_handle.valid());
RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Goal status =%d", future_goal_handle.get().get()->get_status());
```

`future_goal_handle.valid()` returns 1
`future_goal_handle.get()` blocks the execution

**Comment by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on 2023-03-23**:
Maybe it is related with this open issue: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/2130

**Comment by [GuimingChen](https://answers.ros.org/users/52726/guimingchen/) on 2023-03-23**:
Oh, and I just realized that I forgot to add `rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete` to block the waiting until the future is ready. Based on the documentation, [This doc](https://docs.ros2.org/dashing/api/rclcpp_action/classrclcpp__action_1_1Client.html) page did mention that "A future that completes when the goal has been accepted or rejected." Maybe worth give it a shot to add the following code before calling `future_goal_handle.get()`:

```
rclcpp::spin_until_future_complete(node, future_goal_handle);
```

**Comment by [GuimingChen](https://answers.ros.org/users/52726/guimingchen/) on 2023-03-23**:
you may need `node->get_node_base_interface()` depending on what exactly the `node` here mean

**Comment by [Acwok](https://answers.ros.org/users/30443/acwok/) on 2023-03-24**:
It is indeed the `spin_until_future_complete()` that was missing.
Thank you @GuimingChen !